# How to make google apps script buttons work on phones and tablets; and how to access files via apps script

Tags: android, iphone, google-apps-script, button

I know how to create a button in Googlesheets and they work fine when using a chromebook.
but how do you make the buttons work on phones and tablets.

-------------------

Comment: Try using checkboxes for buttons and run them with an onEdit

Comment: Hi. we work on a "one question per post" basis. Would you please edit your question to remove one question, and create a new post for it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.